# Can I install Sql Server 2008 on my windows home server

Tags: windows-home-server, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to do more with my Windows Home server than file sharing and backups.

Has anyone tried installing SQL Server 2008 (any version, but I'm using Professional) on a Windows Home Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 Standard is currently running on my Windows Home Server without issue.

---

You can install it on [Windows XP and Windows Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#EE32) which have the same codebase as WHS so I suppose it's not too surprising that it took.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SQL Express will definitely work. I wouldn't know about the full versions, but I imagine Developer will work too.

Just be careful where you store your database files if you're planning to let them grow.